# What happens when an application's database server reaches storage capacity?

Tags: database, web-applications, bigdata

Let's say I had a web application where users could store up to a gigabyte of their own data. The pages and code are stored on an application server, and the data is stored on a database server. The user requests a page from the application server, and the application server gets the data for the page from the database server.

Simple enough, but what happens when the database server gets full but the amount of users my application has keeps growing? Say the database server had a terabyte hard drive, and 1000 users were using all their available space. The physical disk space left is dwindling fast and new users have nowhere to put their data.

I imagine this is a fairly common occurrence for nearly every web application ever, so how is this remedied? How do designers of highly scalable web applications overcome the requirement for massive data storage?

Answer (score 1):

How can you remedy a full disk? You can stop service, or delete data or provision more storage.

This situation is very undesirable because there is no good alternative at the moment this happens. Stopping service is very expensive and not a solution at all. Deleting data should have happened when there was some headroom left. It should not happen at the last possible moment. Provisioning more storage can take a long time. It should have happened before the disk became full.

**The way this is dealt with is to not let the disk become full in the first place.** Monitor storage utilization and always keep enough of it available.

If it turns out that storing all data is too expensive you have a problem with the business model. This is not a technical issue. Decide what data is profitable to keep and automatically remove the rest.

> I imagine this is a fairly common occurrence for nearly every web application ever

It is common to have to decide what to do with data. It is very uncommon, and a failure of operations, to let a disk become full.

> How do designers of highly scalable web applications overcome the requirement for massive data storage?

They either do not overcome the requirement and store everything, or they decide what to delete.

Comment: But what about situations where data can't be deleted because it belongs to a customer who is paying for the storage (such as in SaaS or cloud hosting)?

Let's take Salesforce for example, a big customer relationship management system. It has thousands of companies' data and it can't just delete what it feels like to make room for more customers.

My question was more in the vein of "how do web applications store huge amounts of data when the situation can't be remedied with either getting a bigger disk or just deleting stuff"

Comment: @Adam this is an impossible situation to solve. You define all solutions that are taken in practice as impossible. The end result is that there is no solution.; Salesforces must keep all data, that's true. But they *can* get bigger disks (or just more of them). And that's what they do. Don't you think so? I probably misunderstand your point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx which didn't quite answer my question but did provide me with a "close enough" solution. Keeping user data in separate databases, provisioning new ones when needed, and limiting the maximum storage per user.

Of course this is relevant to a CRM or similar SaaS application, and architecture will differ greatly per site.

Comment: I now understand. You want to know how "potentially infinite" storage is provided on a technical level. The first stage of scaling is adding disks to the database server (or the SAN). The next stage is scale-out which implies a distributed storage solution. This can be done using off-the-shelf systems like Hadoop, HBase, Cassandra and many others. They manage the scale-out over many servers. It can also be done manually by sharding at the application layer (spreading customers over servers). Does that help?

Comment: Yes! I'll look into how distributed storage solutions work. Thanks :)